# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php

I am new in php, and wonder why I getting this, need expert to guide.  Thanks.

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function rowCount() on resource in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\xxx.php on line 9

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';
$conn = null;

$sqlGetFeedback = "Select * from t_abc";

$resFB = $conn->query($sqlGetFeedback);
$rows = array();

if($resFB->rowCount()){
    echo json_encode($resFB->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} else {    
    echo '[{}]';
}
?>
```

Comment: You're doing `$conn = null;` immediately after `include 'connect_db.php';`, that's why the error.

Answer (score 0):

`$conn` is an object reference that you have set to `null` which essentially means "no object there". And then you call the method `query` that operates on an object, which you don't have because it is `null`.

In your included file `connect_db.php` maybe there is a constructor for the object that implements the method `query` or there is a factory function that returns a constructed object that implements `query`.

I hope you know some basics about object oriented programming, or else all this perhaps won't help you much. In this case grab a book learn about this programming paradigm first.

Comment: I found the problem is not from the $conn, but is from the function called rowCount is the sample code from mysql.  I need it in Postgresql.  Any advice how to replace the rowCount in Postgresql statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is referencing the $conn = null.
Soln:
It's either you place the include connect_db.php after the $conn

Or

Remove the $conn = null entirely.
You should have $conn in your connect_db.php

Comment: I found the problem is not from the $conn, but is from the function called rowCount is the sample code from mysql. I need it in Postgresql. Any advice how to replace the rowCount in Postgresql statement?

Comment: Let's see your connect_db.php script